# when i check the data that i need to fetch from a server i got an error of map with a null

Tags: dictionary, flutter, dart, null, fetch

[i got this error when i try to map a list that i need to get from a server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YulUX.png)

---

** you can find the code that causes a noSuchMethodError**

```
     Future<void> fetchAndSetOrders() async {
    const url = 'https://flutter-shop-app-d675a.firebaseio.com/orders.json';
    final response = await http.get(url);
    final List<OrderItem> loadedOrders = [];
    final extractedData = json.decode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
    if (extractedData == null) {
      return;
    }
    extractedData.forEach((orderId, orderData) {
      loadedOrders.add(
        OrderItem(
          id: orderId,
          totalAmount: orderData['totalamount'],
          dateTime: DateTime.parse(orderData['dateTime']),
          products: (orderData['products'] as List<dynamic>)
              .map(
                (item) => CartItem(
                      id: item['id'],
                      price: item['price'],
                      quantity: item['quantity'],
                      title: item['title'],
                    ),
              )
              .toList(),
        ),
      );
    });
    _orders = loadedOrders.reversed.toList();
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some orders don't have products, for example:

```
"-M5vdHyPFMBDzyx-5_FW":{
  "dateTime":"2020-04-27T14:38:15.033916",
  "totalamount":0.0
},
```

As a result the expression `(orderData['products'] as List<dynamic>)` evaluates to `null` and calling `map` function on it breaks your program.

To fix it you can use an Elvis operator like so:

```dart
products: (orderData['products'] as List<dynamic>)
  ?.map((item) => CartItem(...))
  ?.toList() ?? [],
```